# Django, Informix, ibm_db and DB2 data server driver

Tags: django, db2, informix

I'm trying to connect to IDS(v11.50) from django(v1.3.1) using IBM DB2 Data Server Driver (ODBC)(v10.1) and ibm_db (https://code.google.com/p/ibm-db/). Simple query like 'select distinct adm_audit.action from adm_audit' from django to driver transfers into `select distinct "adm_audit"."action" from "adm_audit"` and generate error:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver][IDS/UNIX64] A syntax error has occurred.
```

I tried to execute same sql statement in db2cli, and it returns same error:

```
    >select distinct "adm_audit"."action" from "adm_audit"
    select distinct "adm_audit"."action" from "adm_audit"
    SQLError: rc = 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    SQLGetDiagRec: SQLState     : 42000
              fNativeError : -201
              szErrorMsg   : [IBM][CLI Driver][IDS/UNIX64] A syntax error has occurred.
              cbErrorMsg   : 58
```

if quotes are removed, statement completes successfully:

```
    > select distinct adm_audit.action from adm_audit
    select distinct adm_audit.action from adm_audit
    FetchAll:  Columns: 1
      action
       ...results...
    FetchAll: 13 rows fetched.
```

Anu suggestions? 
Appreciate any help.

Problem solved.

1) DELIMIDENT variable

2) change from ibm_db_django -> operation.py around 176 line,  string

`"name = upper( name )"`

to

`"name = lower( name )"`

(and import `lower' from string class)

Comment: Are you able to run such query from Informix tools like `dbaccess`?

Comment: Same result. `201: A syntax error has occurred.` after `select distinct "adm_audit"."action" from "adm_audit"`.Seems, this is ibm_db trouble.

Comment: By default, Informix recognizes both `'` and `"` quotes around strings (they have to be the same at both ends, of course).  To recognize a double-quoted string as a delimited identifier, you have to force its hand with the DELIMIDENT environment variable, or an equivalent setting in the API's connect string.  The setting cannot be changed once a session is in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is environment variable `DELIMIDENT` which can control usage of double quotes. Set it to `y` to use it only around delimited SQL identifiers.

More info: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls1077.htm

I tested it with ODBC and JDBC and it works the same, for `SELECT * FROM "aaa"`:

- without `DELIMIDENT` set, with default `DELIMIDENT=n`: error
- with `DELIMIDENT=y` set: query works

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is only a half of a problem. Now I find out, that Informix prior v11.70xC2 does not support case insensitive databases, so it shows error for table name strings (in quotes) in upper case.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled with ibm_db_django for Informix a bit.

Results can be found here: https://github.com/nutztherookie/ibm_db_django

It's not perfect, but it does support inspectdb, for example :)